# My journey learning programming. Looking for guidance ~ where do I go from here?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, software-development, career-switch, code

I started to learn to programming sometime in May about 4 months ago, I had tried to learn before, but this time was with real college courses. I feel like this is the perfect career for me, but I have no one around me that is at all interested or knowledgable in programming or technology. I’ve posted my story of learning programming in hopes that someone can give me some guidance on where to go from here. I know this is a pretty open question and I don’t expect that anyone can tell me exactly what to do. I am more so looking for general advice based on the current job market and tech field. Also people’s general opinions on most important topics for me to focus on; I added my current focuses but I am by no means tied to what I chose for the time being. In addition if anyone is kind enough to check out one of my projects on GitHub I would SERIOUSLY appreciate any second opinions. Also open to staying in contact with anyone in a similar position who would like to learn together. You can read the last 2-3 paragraphs if this is too long as well. Here is my story:

I've always been interested in technology but it took me awhile to suck it up and learn to code. I explored and learned a lot about many things such as business, finance, psychology, neuroscience, and a few more; all professions that centered on moving systems that work together. I love all of these topics, but as I studied I kept coming back to programming being the best fit for me. This was largely because all these professions require programmers, so I could potentially work in finance or medical research even though I don’t have multiple degrees. Besides that I do really enjoy programming and believe I have a lot of potential if I keep on progressing.

After learning bits and pieces of Python and SQL through the years I decided to get serious and signed up for some college classes around March 2023. I took 3 courses (Program Design, Computer Concepts, and Information Security) and got a 95+ in each one. In these courses I developed a better understanding of the fundamentals of how networks & computers work, concepts of Program Design, and Basics of Cyber/Information Security.

I am now continuing to learn independently through Udemy courses and other various online resources. My focus is to get highly proficient with Java due to its transferable C-style syntax, it being platform independent, and it's verbosity; requiring one to understand more deeply than python. My current focuses are on more universal and transferable concepts and principles; My classes are on Design Patterns & Principles (SOLID, Gang of Four), Multithreading & Concurrency, and Performance Tuning & Memory Management. There is also one course on Spring, Spring-Boot, and Hibernate.

There are some projects I am working on to upload to GitHub and demonstrate the skills I've developed. Having a strong financial background, I have one large java project that will be a financial program for technical analysis, back-testing, and algorithmic trading. I have so far only finished the charts with historical data, but plan on also adding live charts, a panel for fundamental data and/or general state-of-the-market data such as GDP, CPI, Treasury Yields, etc. This is ok as the charting is the hardest part to get working with no issues (JFreeChart SMH) and I am almost completely done with that (functional just a few small bugs).

For smaller projects so far I have built a similar application Python. Currently it is just proof I can code in Python. Initially I just wanted to see how I would do the same function in Python since it is referred to as easier, especially for data visualization. I decided using python charting libraries would take from the learning aspect of my larger project. Anyway this program lets you choose from 2 different APIs (AlphaVantage API or MarketData API) then after it gets the data you choose from a GUI base chart or a Web based chart (MPL-Finance for GUI Chart  ||  Dash & Plotly for Browser Chart)

Both of the financial charting programs are on my GitHub, but only the java program has sample data to use without an API key.

Some projects I'm considering or want to build for employers are as follows:

- Web-Scraper (potentially as part of a automated twitter account project, will probably run as a terminal program)
- A Java web-app (web apps seem to be all the rage; I will probably do this for my big project when finished or at least a bit more polished/functional)
- A Python web-app (maybe a program to calculate an in depth analysis of average mineral, vitamin, and caloric content of a meal based on a recipe/portions; eventually being able to track such intake over time for each user)
- An Encryption program (largely for me to dive in to the subject matter)
- I want to make a network based program to learn and demonstrate said knowledge, but I’m not sure what to do for that yet

Ultimately I am just wondering where do I go from here? I am comfortable with Java/Python and I am brushing up on my PostGreSQL since I learned it years ago. I can read C/C#/JavaScript/HTML/CSS and feel confident I could put something together if had to. Should I just keep building stuff to show my consistency and dedication? In addition to that, if I should just keep learning, where should my focus be? I know Design, Concurrency, and Performance/Memory Tuning will be important for programming in general, but are Spring/Spring-Boot/Hibernate relevant skills that I can use to get work? I really need to start working asap, and I’m hoping that I’m almost ready to be programming professionally in some capacity. I’d love any advice as to where I should be to get a junior dev job, what I can do freelance in the meantime, what I should consider focusing on and why, or how I can improve my coding skills. Thank you for even reading this far.

I sincerely appreciate any advice, be it general guidance or if you were kind enough to take the time to look at one of my projects on GitHub (Username = @EntryInvalid). I don’t have anyone in my life that has any knowledge or ambitions towards technology or programming, so it has been very difficult not having a second opinion on anything. One way or another I am going to keep on going refining my skills on my own, but It be great if I had a better idea of where my skills are and what my biggest focus should be.

**Looking forward to hearing back,**

**EntryInvalid ~ ConceptualSoup**

~

*TLDR*

*Ive been coding for about 6 months now and feel pretty proficient in Java and Python. I have a few Udemy courses and a few projects I am working on. I have 2 active projects that are both posted on GitHub should anyone be able to review a bit of one. I am trying to determine the most sound way to progress and get a job in the field as soon as possible; intrinsically this also means ways to grow as fast as possible be it from hard work or focusing on the right areas. The classes I am taking, my current projects, and projects I want to build are all listed above. My specific interests are a bit ambiguous for now but I think I mainly like back-end development - this determination will require time actually working in the industry.*

Comment: Do you have another degree in another major?  That will help.  Also I would say finish at least 1 polished web app and also learn about SQL as that is important and just apply to jobs.  Doing projects at home doesn't substitute for working experience.

Answer (score 4):

#### You haven't learned programming in four months.

You've made a start.  The question is what are you planning to do from here.  If you're looking for a job you'll be competing with people who went to college for 4 years, so why would a company choose you? Companies aren't going to hire you based on your GIT directories. My experience with self-taught coders is they had some type of entry via another job, like working in a plant that needed some coding done.  There are tons of coders like this, but you need to be someplace first to get that break.

I don't mean to discourage you, but recognize that jobs are competitive.  Formal schooling will give you a leg up.

Comment: Not discouraging at all - I appreciate the honesty. I fully understand that my knowledge is very limited compared to my competition, that is why I figure if I am to obtain a job like this as opposed to college (not possible right now), that I am best off focusing on a specific task or area that I can work in while I continue to learn. My professors felt that I was almost ready to start applying for internships so I'm gonna just keep going.

Answer (score 2):

> I don’t have anyone in my life that has any knowledge or ambitions towards technology or programming

The times when you learned you job from working with your dad in his business are long gone. Nobody has anyone in their life with ambitions or knowledge of their preferred job.

That is why there are formalized apprenticeships (instead of working for your Uncle for food and a place to sleep) and college degrees (instead of reading up on it by yourself in a library).

If you are serious about making this a job, you need a plan on how to achieve a formal certification. Not some online thing. A serious education, with a serious real human teacher and a certificate widely recognized. Doesn't need to be a prestiguous college. But a BSc from a real, physically existing college (or the apprenticeship equivalent in your country), not some made up title from an institution nobody ever heard of.

Comment: I understand that completely and more than anything I'd love to go to college, but unfortunately that is not an option for me right now and probably wont be an option for awhile. In the meantime it's something I really enjoy, and even though I know my knowledge is very limited at the moment I feel Its something I can be very good at.

Comment: I know several professional software engineers that are teaching their kids to code -  so I think it's a stretch to say that those days are "long gone".